# Failed to resolve entry for package "material-symbols"

Tags: sveltekit

After installing material-symbols using npm the following message is shown in the console

My steps

1. Run in the console `npm i material-symbols@latest`
2. Add `import 'material-symbols';` at the top of the `__layout.svelte` file
3. Add `<span class="material-symbols-outlined">face</span>` to the component file
4. Open console
5. Error message is shown

Error message

> Failed to resolve entry for package "material-symbols". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json: Failed to resolve entry for package "material-symbols". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was able to run this package by changing the approach. I replaced step 2 with CSS imports.

Instead of

```js
// __layout.svelte

import 'material-symbols';

...
```

I created 'app.css' file in the src folder. Added `@import 'material-symbols';` at the top of its file. Imported `app.css` into `__layout.svelte`.

```css
/* app.css */

@import 'material-symbols';
```

```
// __layout.svelte 

- import 'material-symbols';
+ import '../app.css';

...
```

It works